# How to get the URL for the re sized image

Tags: forms, media, files

I have built a custom form in Drupal 7. The form has a file type field which allows the user to upload an image. I'm using the below code in the submit function to save and re size the image:

```
function adddeals_submit($form, &$form_state){
    global $user;

    $file = $form_state['storage']['file'];
    // We are done with the file, remove it from storage.
    unset($form_state['storage']['file']);
    // Make the storage of the file permanent
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    // Save file status.
    file_save($file);
    //get the url for the saved file
    $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
    echo $url;
    echo '<br>';

    $destination = 'public://ImageThumbnail';
    $img = image_load($file->uri);
    image_resize($img, 200, 200);
    $result = image_save($img,$destination);
    echo $result;


    exit;
  }
```

The image is re-sizing and saving correctly as the $result is printing 1. I need to know how to get the URL for the re sized image. Am I missing something?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I think in this case, you can get the URL by reloading the $img object as this object is updated when saving the resized image

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use your approach because as you can see by yourself now you have no reference to the resized image, what I would do is use [image_style_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_path/7) :

```
function adddeals_submit($form, &$form_state){
    global $user;

    $file = $form_state['storage']['file'];
    unset($form_state['storage']['file']);
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);
    $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
    // this
    $derivative_uri = image_style_path($your_style, $file->uri);
    $url = image_style_create_derivative(image_style_load('your_style'), $file->uri, $derivative_uri);
}
```

This creates a folder in your files folder with your style name and stores the image there, then wherever in your code you want to get that image you just reutilize this code:

```
$derivative_uri = image_style_path($your_style, $file->uri);
$url = image_style_create_derivative(image_style_load('your_style'), $file->uri, $derivative_uri);
```

Drupal checks if an image is there and gives you back the `$url`, if it's not there it creates the image applying your style.

P.S. you need to register your style in configuration and once the style folder is created check it's permission settings.